# iOS, UITextView wrapping every other line

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I'm pretty sure that my data source has no funky \P elements, but I'm seeing lots of wrapping of the text in my UITextView for no apparent reason. The text does not wrap in the console.  Am I missing something in the UITextView properties?

```
UITextView *tv = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
tv.editable = NO;
tv.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Courier" size: 12.0f];
tv.text = dm.abstract;
tv.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
tv.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[view addSubview:tv];
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Screenshot, please? It'd be easier to find out the cause.

Comment: Here's a screen.  Sorry for the blur, but its sensitive content.  You can see how some of the text wrapped.  It should be one contiguous block except for when a word happens to fall in the wrap threshold.

Comment: Load some non-sensitive random content into the text view and then post a screenshot.

Comment: When I load up text like tv.text = @"the quick brown fox.." there doesn't seem to be a problem with the wrapping.  Could this be due to the fact that the data is coming from a FMDB sequel response?  It looks like every other line is suffering from excessive wrapping.

Comment: Sounds like there are newlines between the lines you see being wrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After outputting the text from sql to a file and viewing its CRLFs with vim, I found that there are indeed CRLFs in the TextView input text, so UITextView is doing the right thing.  My bad.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` adds some padding by default. This can cause text wrapping. You can try removing the default padding.

This brings the left edge of the text to the left edge of the container:

```
self.textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
```

This causes the top of the text to align with the top of the container:

```
self.textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried with the padding removed and although the wrapping is changed, its same deal with the random wrapping.  I guess this confirms that there are no specific characters causing the wrap.